# Multiple left-outer join results in duplicated rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a big table having Incidents. With this I want to attach values from Incident Attachment and Incident Comments. I have used Left outer join as there may or may not be any comments OR attachment for a Incident.
Now when I use multiple outer join i get duplicated rows.

There is a incidentID value that is common for all the tables

```
INC1   ATT1   COMMENT1
INC1   ATT1   COMMENT2
INC1   ATT2   COMMENT1
INC1   ATT2   COMMENT2
```

But actually the output should be:

```
INC1   ATT1   COMMENT1
INC1   ATT2   COMMENT2
```

so that the attachment and the comment values are independent when attaching themselves to the incident table.

```
select inc,att.attname,comment.commenttext 
from   inc 
       left outer join att inc.incidentID=att.incidentID
       left outer join comment inc.incidentID=comment .incidentID
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Tangential: Your query is missing a couple of `on`s

Comment: @MikeRyan: Re: "There no obvious reason why it would do this": I think you must be misunderstanding something in the question, because what it describes is exactly the normal behavior of `JOIN`. There's effectively a Cartesian product between `att` and `comment`, since nothing in any `ON` or `WHERE` clause constrains a relationship between them.

Comment: 6_2010/01/07 has 4 attachment and 7 comments, hence it is returning 28 rows while effectively it should not be more than 7 rows

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT inc.incident_id,
  comments.comment_text,
  attachments.attachemnt_url
FROM incidents inc 
  left outer  comments ON inc.incident_id = comments.incident_id  
  left outer  attachments ON inc.incident_id   =attachments.incident_id 
 where inc.incident_id   = '6_2010/01/07'

Comment: Please do suggest if the left outer join is the correct implementation or if this needs to completely changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things I'm taking away from your responses so far is that, for a given incident, there's no direct relationship between its attachments and its comments.
If I understand that correctly, you want to treat an incident as a simple "container" for attachments and comments, and you just want a listing of each.  Which
attachment happens to appear in the same row as a particular comment is incidental to you.

TEST DATA:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE inc (incidentid NUMBER, incname VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO inc VALUES (1,'incident 1');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO inc VALUES (2,'incident 2');

1 row created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE att (att_id NUMBER, incidentid NUMBER, attname VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (101, 1, 'attachment 1');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (102, 1, 'attachment 2');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (103, 1, 'attachment 3');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (104, 1, 'attachment 4');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (105, 1, 'attachment 5');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (110, 2, 'attachment A');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (111, 2, 'attachment B');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO att VALUES (112, 2, 'attachment C');

1 row created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE comments (comment_id NUMBER, incidentid NUMBER, commenttext VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO comments VALUES (201, 1, 'first comment');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO comments VALUES (202, 1, 'second comment');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO comments VALUES (203, 1, 'third comment');

1 row created.
```

PROPOSED QUERY:

```
SQL> WITH a AS (
  2      SELECT att.incidentid
  3      ,      COUNT(att.att_id) rows_per_incident
  4      FROM   att
  5      GROUP BY att.incidentid
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT comments.incidentid
  8      ,      COUNT(comments.comment_id) rows_per_incident
  9      FROM   comments
 10      GROUP BY comments.incidentid
 11  )
 12  ,   b AS  (
 13      SELECT inc.incidentid
 14      ,      inc.incname
 15      ,      ROW_NUMBER()
 16             OVER (PARTITION BY inc.incidentid ORDER BY NULL) row_num
 17      FROM   inc
 18      ,     (SELECT ROWNUM multiplier FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(rows_per_incident) FROM a))
 19  )
 20  ,   c AS (
 21      SELECT  att.att_id
 22      ,       att.incidentid
 23      ,       att.attname
 24      ,       ROW_NUMBER()
 25              OVER (PARTITION BY att.incidentid ORDER BY att.att_id) att_rn
 26      FROM    att
 27  )
 28  ,   d AS (
 29      SELECT comments.comment_id
 30      ,      comments.incidentid
 31      ,      comments.commenttext
 32      ,      ROW_NUMBER()
 33             OVER (PARTITION BY comments.incidentid ORDER BY comments.comment_id) comm_rn
 34      FROM   comments
 35  )
 36  ,   e AS (
 37      SELECT  c.incidentid
 38      ,       c.att_id
 39      ,       c.attname
 40      ,       c.att_rn      rn
 41      ,       d.comment_id
 42      ,       d.commenttext
 43      FROM    c
 44      ,       d
 45      WHERE   c.incidentid = d.incidentid (+)
 46      AND     c.att_rn     = d.comm_rn (+)
 47      UNION ALL
 48      SELECT  TO_NUMBER(NULL) incidentid
 49      ,       TO_NUMBER(NULL) att_id
 50      ,       NULL            attname
 51      ,       d.comm_rn       rn
 52      ,       d.comment_id
 53      ,       d.commenttext
 54      FROM    d
 55      WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  NULL
 56                          FROM    c
 57                          WHERE   c.incidentid = d.incidentid
 58                          AND     c.att_rn     = d.comm_rn)
 59  )
 60  ,   f AS (
 61  SELECT  b.incidentid
 62  ,       b.incname
 63  ,       b.row_num
 64  ,       e.att_id
 65  ,       e.attname
 66  ,       e.comment_id
 67  ,       e.commenttext
 68  FROM    b
 69      LEFT OUTER JOIN e ON  b.incidentid = e.incidentid
 70                        AND b.row_num    = e.rn
 71  )
 72  SELECT  f.incidentid
 73  ,       f.incname
 74  ,       f.att_id
 75  ,       f.attname
 76  ,       f.comment_id
 77  ,       f.commenttext
 78  FROM    f
 79  WHERE   NOT (f.att_id IS NULL AND f.comment_id IS NULL)
 80  ORDER BY f.incidentid
 81  ,        f.row_num
 82  ;

INCIDENTID INCNAME                  ATT_ID ATTNAME              COMMENT_ID COMMENTTEXT
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
         1 incident 1                  101 attachment 1                201 first comment
         1 incident 1                  102 attachment 2                202 second comment
         1 incident 1                  103 attachment 3                203 third comment
         1 incident 1                  104 attachment 4
         1 incident 1                  105 attachment 5
         2 incident 2                  110 attachment A
         2 incident 2                  111 attachment B
         2 incident 2                  112 attachment C

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```